# Adding Functionality of RFID in android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Is there any specific protocol needed to be used in android studio for intent of using RFID reader to read NFC Tag? Both of the reader and NFC Tag have a high frequency ( 13.5 MHz )
I have used the normal protocol of detecting NFC. But, the RFID reader does not detect the NFC Tag when the tag is scanned. Is there any specific protocol for the android application to use the RFID reader in the android application?

as requested. this are my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Enable NFC when the activity is in the foreground
        nfcManager.enableNFC(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Disable NFC when the activity goes into the background
        nfcManager.disableNFC(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSerialIoManager();
        if (serialPort != null) {
            try {
                serialPort.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            serialPort = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            // Retrieve the list of technologies supported by the tag
            String[] techList = tag.getTechList();

            // Check if app supports any of the desired technologies
            if (supportsDesiredTechnology(techList)) {
                // App supports at least one of the desired technologies
                // Implement logic here to handle the supported technology

                // Create or obtain the directory
                File directory = createFile();

                if (directory != null) {
                    // Read data from the NFC tag using the Ndef technology
                    String dataFromNFC = getDataFromNFC(tag);

                    if (!dataFromNFC.isEmpty()) {
                        // Calculate the MD5 hash of the data
                        String md5Hash = calculateMD5(dataFromNFC);

                        // Write data and MD5 hash to the file
                        writeDataToFile(directory, md5Hash);

                        // Display a message or perform actions based on the data read
                        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Data: " + dataFromNFC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "MD5 Hash: " + md5Hash, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case where no NFC data was read
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No NFC data read.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle the case where directory is null
                    Log.e("FileIO", "Directory is null, cannot write to file.");
                }
            } else {
                // Your app does not support any of the desired technologies
                // Handle this situation (e.g., display a message)
                handleUnsupportedTechnology();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the (build-in) NFC reader or an external one ? Please post your code you are struggling with as there are some methods to detect and read a tag, depending on this there are several choices, thanks.

Comment: I am using an external rfid reader to detect the nfc card. Can I use the nfc protocol and implement it for the rfid reader?

Comment: What is the make and Model of the External Reader? What software library are you using to drive it as the code has some similarities to using a Internal NFC hardware it but not the same, for example where does `nfcManager` class come from?

Comment: from what I can understand from your question is that the nfcManager is a java code built on a different page that will be implemented into the main code. to handle the task of receiving the nfc tag more efficient. the external reader is RFID. let's say if the reader is RF881 RFID reader. can I use the protocol of nfc tag as per mentioned above?` I am using an external antena to connect with the reader

Comment: have settled all the problems faced